# Is $a_n = o(n)$ different from $\max a_i = o(n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Let $a_i$ be a sequence of real numbers. If I know that $a_n = o(n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, is it equivalent to say that:

$$\max_i^n a_i = o(n)$$

At first glance they seem different (the second seems stronger), but I think I am able to prove that they are the same:

Assume that $a_n = o(n)$:

Then, $\max a_i = \max \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_{n-j}, ..., a_n \} = \max \{c, o(n)\} = o(n)$

Now going the other way, assume $\max_i^n a_i = o(n)$:

$$a_n \leq \max^n_i a_i = o(n)$$

**My question**

Is my reasoning correct? Is there a more general statement hiding here?

Comment: What exactly does your second statement, $a\leq \max = \mathcal{o}(n)$ mean? Recall that "equality" in Bachmann–Landau notation does not denote true equality and is not generally a *symmetric relation*, so appending two such "equalities" is ambiguous. Are you stating that $a_n$ is also $\mathcal{o}(n)$ or just that $\max$ is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first implication is true, the second has a counterexample:

$$a_n := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if n is even} \\ -n & \text{if n is odd} \end{cases}$$

Comment: ah ok good point, i should be careful with the signs. But i guess if we assume the sequence is positive then the two statements are equivalent

Comment: Actually also in that case it's not true, you can consider the sequence:
$a_n := \begin{cases} n & \text{if n is even} \\ 1 & \text{if n is odd} \end{cases}$

in this case: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ doesn't exist, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\max a_n}{n}$ does.   

By the way you asked about what it's called "superior limit", here you have a reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior

For a sequence or a function having a superior or inferior limit is much weaker than having a proper limit. So it's often used if you don't know the limit exists.